# How to find out whether subversion working directory is locked by svn?

Tags: python, svn

A python script is running two parallel python processes ( created via os.fork() ) each of which eventually tries to check out a subversion repository leaf into the same working copy dir.

Before running 'svn co ...' command in a sub-process ( via python subprocess module ) the parent python code checks if the working copy dir already exists.

```
  if os.path.isdir(checkout_dir):
     # working copy dir already exists
     return checkout_dir
```

So that if it does there shouldn't be any 'svn co' running, but rather immediate return from the parent function.

Nevertheless some collision happened and one of the python processes failed on 'svn co ..' with the following error.

```
checked-out failed: svn: Working copy '/tmp/qm_23683' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)**
```

So the first question is why the working copy dir existence check didn't work and the second - is there a way to find out that a working copy dir is locked by svn and loop until it is unlocked?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a potential race condition, in that something like the following can happen:

1. Process A checks to see if the directory exists (it doesn't yet).
2. Process B checks to see if the directory exists (it doesn't yet).
3. Process A invokes `svn`, which creates the directory.
4. Process B invokes `svn`, which subsequently fails.

An easy way to avoid this is to have each process attempt to *create* the directory rather than checking for its existence.  If the other process has already created the directory, the other process is guaranteed to get a well-defined error code under a very wide variety of platforms and filesystems.  For instance, this is one of the only reliable ways to do synchronization on many implementations of NFS.  Luckily, `svn` won't care if the working directory already exists.

The Python code would look something like this:

```
import os, errno

# ...

try:
  os.mkdir(dirName)
except OSError, e:
  if e.errno != errno.EEXIST: raise # some other error
  print 'Directory already exists.'
else:
  print 'Successfully created new directory.'
```

This technique is easy to implement, very reliable, and useful in a wide variety of situations.

Answer (score 4):

Within the directory, there should be a directory called '.svn'. Within this, a file named 'locked' indicates that the directory is locked.